# Liferea plain text downloads?

Tags: text, rss, liferea

Have any Liferea (Linux feed reader) users been able to download plain text copies of their RSS feeds? I understand that it provides for offline viewing, so I assume that some sort of local caching is taking place, but don't know PHP so I can't modify it myself.

https://sourceforge.net/projects/liferea/?source=navbar

If impossible in Liferea, does anyone know of a simple way to download plain text copies of an RSS feed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that with "plain text" you actually mean "raw", Liferea offers no ways to do that.

You can however user your favorite web browser: just open the feed and save it. For example, you can download the feed of Planet Ubuntu in **Firefox** visiting http://planet.ubuntu.com/rss20.xml and selecting **File → Save Page As...** from the menu.

If you prefer the terminal, you can use **wget** or **curl**:

```
wget http://planet.ubuntu.com/rss20.xml
```

Comment: Fair enough. I'm familiar with manually downloading xml files, but since my goal is ultimately the creation of a self-updating, plaint text database of many RSS feeds, it would take too long to do this by hand. I'm currently using Google Reader, but they don't have any download functionality. Can you think of a feed reader that allows users to download copies of their articles?

Comment: @nitrl: If you want a collection of RSS files that is periodically updated, then this is a totally different question. Personally I don't know any application that does so, I'd use a **cron** script. I must also say that Liferea stores its feeds in a Sqlite3 database, so you may use that. If you're going to open a new question, please _state what you are trying to do_, because it's very difficult to give a precise answer without enough information.

Comment: Thanks for the tip about **cron**, and I'll make sure to clarify next time.